# Prepend to a list in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component named task that contains a row of form inputs relating to the task.  `tasks` is retrieved from a GET JSON request (existing entries).

```
<task v-for="task in tasks" :task="task"></task>
```

Now, I want to have a button to add a new blank row of inputs so they can add new entries.

```
<button type="button" @click="addTask()">New</button>
```

I tried unshifting an empty object to the tasks:

```
addTask() {
    this.tasks.unshift({});
},
```

However, this just duplicates the last row of my tasks rather than adding a new row to the beginning of the tasks.

What's the best way to prepend items to an existing list?

Comment: I think this is because you don't have a [`key` attribute](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Components-and-v-for)

Comment: @thanksd yes, looks like you're right.  Thanks.  I can use `task.id` for the key for existing entries and I guess I just have to generate some temporary key for new entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `v-for` directive on a component, you need to specify a `key` attribute, providing a value that will be unique for each component. Otherwise, Vue will try to reuse elements.

From the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key):

> The `key` special attribute is primarily used as a hint for Vue’s virtual DOM algorithm to identify VNodes when diffing the new list of nodes against the old list. Without keys, Vue uses an algorithm that minimizes element movement and tries to patch/reuse elements of the same type in-place as much as possible.

In your case, the best way to specify a key would be to associate an `id` property with each `task` and use that as the key:

```
<task v-for="task in tasks" :task="task" :key="task.id"></task>
```